# How to correct a Google Featured Snipppet

Tags: seo, rich-snippets

I finally got the Google featured snipppet in my targeted keyword! (Yay!)

But here's the problem. My webpage lists two dates:

- The date of when xxx was originally written (I'm not including the keyword lest anyone think I'm just spamming)
- The date of a later reprinting.

Google picked the most recent date to answer the question "when was xxx written?"

How can I correct this? If I tamper with it, do I risk losing the featured snipppet?

Comment: How are you providing this data to Google?  Are you using schema markup?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is always to keep your data uniform. Google is good in recognizing things, but don't trust it too much.

As for me, i would maintain two dates on the page, stringently using `datePublished` and `dateModified`, as Google [recommends](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/article).

Comment: I'm using schema with two "WorkExample"s. One is the original publication, and the other is the most recent reprinting. I'll try deleting the second WorkExample from my schema and just having a datePublished and a dateModified for my first WorkExample... and I'll see if that fixes anything.

Comment: I simplified my schema to just have a datePublished and dateModified (no WorkExample). Google still picks the most recent date :(. (I slightly edited my page's content so that I'd know the next time Google crawls my page)